# Get src from img tag with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, image, puppeteer, src

I want to get the link text from the src attribute within an img tag. This is part of the html with the img and src tags:

```
<img alt="" class="responsive-img" src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/6167380a1330877b8265353f2756b127c2226824/0_81_4256_2554/master/4256.jpg?width=300&amp;quality=85&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=max&amp;s=787aa5ddd44a8a66a06120452e228503">
```

I will give the HTML and the script I use because that is what I tried:

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="fc-item__container">
    <div class="fc-item__media-wrapper">
        <div class="fc-item__image-container u-responsive-ratio">
            <picture><!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
                <source
                    media="(min-width: 980px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25), (min-width: 980px) and (min-resolution: 120dpi)"
                    srcset="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/6167380a1330877b8265353f2756b127c2226824/0_81_4256_2554/master/4256.jpg?width=140&amp;quality=45&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=max&amp;dpr=2&amp;s=35c7a9a7cc4e5ebd8fcdfcb67177a8f4 280w">
                <source media="(min-width: 980px)"
                    srcset="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/6167380a1330877b8265353f2756b127c2226824/0_81_4256_2554/master/4256.jpg?width=140&amp;quality=85&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=max&amp;s=f68f029ce1b60ed96581f28a29062e3b 140w">
                <source
                    media="(min-width: 740px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25), (min-width: 740px) and (min-resolution: 120dpi)"
                    srcset="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/6167380a1330877b8265353f2756b127c2226824/0_81_4256_2554/master/4256.jpg?width=140&amp;quality=45&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=max&amp;dpr=2&amp;s=35c7a9a7cc4e5ebd8fcdfcb67177a8f4 280w">
                <source media="(min-width: 740px)"
                    srcset="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/6167380a1330877b8265353f2756b127c2226824/0_81_4256_2554/master/4256.jpg?width=140&amp;quality=85&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=max&amp;s=f68f029ce1b60ed96581f28a29062e3b 140w">
                <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
                <img alt="" class="responsive-img"
                    src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/6167380a1330877b8265353f2756b127c2226824/0_81_4256_2554/master/4256.jpg?width=300&amp;quality=85&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=max&amp;s=787aa5ddd44a8a66a06120452e228503">
            </picture>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the Puppeteer script:

```
const fs = require("node:fs/promises");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.4.1

const url = "https://www.theguardian.com/international";

let browser;
(async () => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    await page.setRequestInterception(true);
    page.on("request", req => {
        if (req.url() !== url) {
            req.abort();
        }
        else {
            req.continue();
        }
    });
    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "domcontentloaded" });
    const img_src = await page.$$eval(".fc-item__container", els =>
        els.map(e => {
            const text = s => e.querySelector(s)?.textContent.trim();
            return {
                src: e.querySelector(".fc-item__media-wrapper .responsive-img src"),
                image: text(".fc-item__media-wrapper .responsive-img"),
            };
        })
    );
    console.log(img_src);
    await fs.writeFile("img_src.json", JSON.stringify(img_src, null, 2));
})()
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
    .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

The script runs but all I get are empty strings, like this:

```
[
  {
    "src": null,
    "image": ""
  },
  {
    "src": null,
    "image": ""
  }
}
]
```

As you can see I tried 2 variations but both doesn't give any result.

```
return {
    src: e.querySelector(".fc-item__media-wrapper .responsive-img src"),
    image: text(".fc-item__media-wrapper .responsive-img"),
};
```

Any help is much appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, great job on blocking requests and disabling JS! This speeds up the script considerably and means we can rely purely on the `view-source:` which simplifies matters.

A problem is:

```
e.querySelector(".fc-item__media-wrapper .responsive-img src"),
```

This says "return the `<src>` tag within an element with `class="responsive-img"` within an element with `class="fc-item__media-wrapper"`". You probably mean:

```js
e.querySelector(".fc-item__media-wrapper .responsive-img")
  ?.getAttribute("src")
```

As for the "text", I'm not sure what that refers to, since there's no text anywhere inside of the `.fc-item__media-wrapper` class.

If you're looking for the kicker text or headline, here's one approach:

```js
const fs = require("node:fs/promises");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.6.3

const url = "<Your URL>";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on("request", req => {
    if (req.url() !== url) {
      req.abort();
    }
    else {
      req.continue();
    }
  });
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const data = await page.$$eval(".fc-item__container", els =>
    els.map(e => {
      const $ = s => e.querySelector(s);
      const text = s => $(s)?.textContent.trim();
      return {
        src: $(".fc-item__media-wrapper .responsive-img")
               ?.getAttribute("src"),
        kicker: text(".fc-item__kicker"),
        headline: text(".fc-item__headline"),
      };
    })
  );
  console.log(data);
  await fs.writeFile("img_src.json", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

By the way, once you've gotten to the point where you're blocking all requests and have disabled JS, you can often [just use fetch (or axios, if you're not on Node 18 yet) with Cheerio](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#using-puppeteer-when-other-tools-are-more-appropriate). This simplifies matters and further speeds things up:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

const url = "<Your URL>";

fetch(url)
  .then(res => {
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw Error(res.statusText);
    }

    return res.text();
  })
  .then(html => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    const data = [...$(".fc-item__container")].map(e => ({
      src: $(e).find(".fc-item__media-wrapper .responsive-img").attr("src"),
      kicker: $(e).find(".fc-item__kicker").text().trim(),
      headline: $(e).find(".fc-item__headline").text().trim(),
    }));
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

See also [this related question from OP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75249765/6243352).

Comment: I also had this line in my setup: `src: $(".fc-item__media-wrapper .responsive-img").getAttribute("src"),` which I didn't mention that possibility in my original post. Looks like I was just  1 question mark shy of the solution. Your extensive answer and comment gives me the right tools to take the next leap to increase my knowledge. Thanks in advance.